# How do I conditionally uninstall pre-requisites based on a CheckBox using Wix?

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, uninstallation, wix3.11

When installing my application, it will detect pre-requisites and install them as needed. Because I don't want the pre-requisites to be uninstalled (normally) I have the 'permanent' attribute set to 'yes'. This is done using the following ExePackage in the Bootstrapper.

```
<ExePackage
    SourceFile ="@@EA_PROJECT_NAME@Installer_SOURCE_DIR@/inst_binaries/postgresql-10.7-1-windows-x64.exe"
    InstallCommand=' --unattendedmodeui minimal --mode unattended --prefix "[ProgramFiles64Folder]\@MANUFACTURER@\postgres" --datadir "[ProgramFiles64Folder]\@MANUFACTURER@\data" --disable-components stackbuilder'
    UninstallCommand=' --unattendedmodeui minimal --mode unattended'
    DetectCondition="( POSTGRESINSTALLED_x64 &gt;= postgres_version ) AND ( NOT REINSTALL )"
    Compressed ="yes"
    Vital ="yes"
    PerMachine="yes"
    Permanent = "yes" 
    Description="Postgres installer"
/>
```

This works fine, without any issues. What I want to do, is conditionally uninstall the pre-requisite. Based on the user selecting a check box, the pre-requisite ExePackage should also be removed. I have tried changed Permanent to a condition, but then the compiler complains it's not a valid yes/no type. I know I have seen installers remove 'all components' options, which removes other applications, so I assume this must be possible, but I am at a loss as to how this is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your BootstrapperApplication will need to handle this scenario. Namely, handle the `IBootstrapperApplication::OnPlanPackageBegin()` callback and change the requested state for this package during uninstall of the bundle to not uninstall.

The Burn engine doesn't provide a declarative way to do this operation.

Comment: If I am using one of the built in bootstrappers, I assume that means I'm SOL?

Comment: The `wixstdba` does not implement a feature like this. Fortunately, you are not SOL (it is possible) but there is a good bit of work needed. Or, maybe, find an already built BA out there that supports this feature.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into making my own then using the OnPlanPackageBegin, always fun to learn something new.